# interfaces for uncommon features in HAL layer

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, hal

I am trying to make a layered architecture and apply hardware abstraction using the HAL concept (hardware abstraction layer).
But I have to stick to the common features only between MCUs, in order to make a generic interface that can be portable between different MCUs. So that I won't have to change the upper layer at all when I move to another MCU.
But I won't be able to use costum features that exist in a specific MCU while others don't have it.

So if there is a specific extra feature in a gpio module that exists in a specific MCU and I want to use it but it doesn't exist in HAL (because it's not a common feature). How can I make an interface for it?

Example:
I want to make a HAL that contains standard interface between atmega328p and Dspic33. Dspic33 has a feature in the Gpio which is Internal Pull Down. This feature does not exist in the atmega328p (so I can't include it in the HAL standard interface).
So if I want to use this uncommon feature how am I going to do that?

Comment: Consider not reinventing the wheel and re-use an existing interface if possible. There is Linux, Zephyr, [CMSIS](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/Driver/Include/Driver_SPI.h#L234), stm32, "iohw.h", mbed... to take inspiration from.

Comment: Universal cross-microcontroller HAL makes no sense at all and it is the reason it has not be written by now. Save your time and effort to do something which makes sense#

Comment: What would be the point of making a "common" interface to a feature only available on on architecture or device?  You usefully implement "facade" - an interface that makes some complicated underlying feature less complicated by wrapping commonly repeated configuration, or access code in a simpler interface.  But doe not confuse that with a HAL in the sense you are using the term.  I suppose you could have a "board" HAL with an interface that supports a superset of features (such as pull-up/down), and uses an assert on targets that do not support it - but really, don't!

Comment: @0___________, that's not really true. AUTOSAR for example has a MCAL, which abstracts the devices with a common interface with certain features to the higher layers, across several MCUs. The thing is, how (as Clifford said) properly facade and abstract features/functionality.

Comment: I think the API function should simply return an error if the caller attempts to use a feature not available from the underlying hardware.

Comment: you put the target specific things behind the HAL so they are hidden.

Answer (score 2):

You can either or all of the following:

- provide an interface with abstracted semantic parameters, with e.g. the meaning "I want to use internal pull down, if present: yes/no"; on platforms which do not have it, the function would effectively be empty
- provide a query API, which allows to check whether a feature is available; if it is then the calling code can use it, with implicit knowledge needed on how to do that (this can be done in the shape of a macro, which would allow querying without the knowledge whether the querying API itself exists, via `#ifdef`; which in turn would allow to skip implementing it on the environments which do not support the feature)
- combine both, i.e. semantic interface with a return value indicating whether the feature has been successfully applied

Comment: how about making a separate .h and .c files with the name dspic33_hal_extend and add the new features in it. Is this method good or does it has some problems. Which one is preferable?

Comment: How would you decide when to include the header?